# [Help]How to run a sproutcore project in production mode?

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-2

How to run a sproutcore project in production mode?

Do you have a good guides for me to learn about sproutcore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A SproutCore project just needs any webserver and where necessary a backend serving its data. When an application written in SproutCore is built, it consists purely of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

In development mode a special local http server (the so-called dev server) is used which allows you to develop the application without having to build the end product. This dev server is provided through the SproutCore build tools.

The current build tools can be installed through NPM: `npm install -g sproutcore`. Older versions of SproutCore used Ruby based build tools.

There are quite a few guides how to write applications using SproutCore. Look for example at https://guides.sproutcore.com. The build tools mentioned in these guides are the Ruby based build tools, but most of the command line commands are identical. It does use different configuration files.

If you have more specific questions, please feel free to drop by in https://gitter.im/sproutcore/sproutcore.

Comment: To addon to this answer; you are free to use something like Apache/Nginx or other services like Heroku or Firebase Hosting to serve it. You have lots of options :-)